# Php file displaying code on browser when called by html form

Tags: php, windows

When ever my php file is called in my web application the code is displayed on browser.

Previously I had opened `.php` file by using `open` with `notepad++` option on Windows.

Now every time I click or run the `.php` file it opens by default with `notepad++`.

Any fix?

Comment: your server is misconfigured and not executing php at all, which usually has nothing to do at all with notepad.

Comment: did you save the file with the extension `.php` or other equivalent extensions?

Comment: Yes the extension is .php

Comment: Php is either not installed or not running.

Comment: are you using a web server like WAMP or XAMP? php requires one to parse

Comment: I think this issue is same as people trying to open a .bat file with a text editor and later the text editor becomes an by default program to open .bat file

Comment: Can you show us how that php file is called in a web app? Are the php tags present?

Comment: don't open php files by double clicking on them.  see below

Answer (score -1):

Once you have open .php file with notepad++ it becomes default for .php file. So whenever in future you open .php file it will open in notepad++. You can change it any time.